# xcode/interface builder button for creating new page

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a button in one of my classes that i create it with xcode/interface builder and I want to connect my button to another class that it create an event based calendar,

I want to press my button but after that it will automatically create another page and inside of that page there is another button --> that when I push that button I can access to the event based calendar page,my question is

how can I remove the second page

here is code that generate second and third pages

AddEvent.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>


@interface AddEvent : UIViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, 
EKEventEditViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {

EKEventViewController *detailViewController;
EKEventStore *eventStore;
EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
NSMutableArray *eventsList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (nonatomic, retain) EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventsList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) EKEventViewController *detailViewController;

- (NSArray *) fetchEventsForToday;



@end
```

AddEvent.m

```
#import "AddEvent.h"

 @interface AddEvent ()

@end

@implementation AddEvent

@synthesize eventsList, eventStore, defaultCalendar, detailViewController;



  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark View lifecycle

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
```

**Here is the code that create the second screen**

```
self.title = @"Events List";

// Initialize an event store object with the init method. Initilize the array for events.
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

self.eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0];

// Get the default calendar from store.
self.defaultCalendar = [self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

//  Create an Add button 
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
                              UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addEvent:)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;



self.navigationController.delegate = self;

  // Fetch today's event on selected calendar and put them into the eventsList array
  [self.eventsList addObjectsFromArray:[self fetchEventsForToday]];


  }



 // Allow event editing.
 detailViewController.allowsEditing = YES;

 // Push detailViewController onto the navigation controller stack
 // If the underlying event gets deleted, detailViewController will remove itself from
//  the stack and clear its event property.
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

  }


  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Add a new event

  // If event is nil, a new event is created and added to the specified event store. New events are 
  // added to the default calendar. An exception is raised if set to an event that is not in the 
  // specified event store.


  - (void)addEvent:(id)sender {
  // When add button is pushed, create an EKEventEditViewController to display the event.
  EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

  // set the addController's event store to the current event store.
  addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;

  // present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
  [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

  addController.editViewDelegate = self;

   }
```

**and also I don't know how should I connect my button in first screen to the third page and remove the second screen**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if possible make a sample project with issue u r facing, upload it some where send the link, that will be easy to find the issue & fix it..

Comment: @rishi thanks I deleted some code

Comment: @justin - every time you are pushing a view controller on navigation controller, so you just need to pop to come back to first view. you can use method popToRootViewContoller from third screen.

Comment: @rishi bu my problem is that I want to remove the second screen and add my button in first screen to the third one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first viewcontrollers's viewDidLoad add the following UIBarButtonItem code for plus button

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
                          UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addEvent:)];
```

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;

and also add the action code

```
- (void)addEvent:(id)sender 
{
// When add button is pushed, create an EKEventEditViewController to display the event.
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];         
// set the addController's event store to the current event store.
addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;

// present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

addController.editViewDelegate = self;

}
```

then add necessary code for adding events in EKEventEditViewController's viewDidLoad.

Comment: thanks for reply but I don't have viewDidLoad un my first ViewControllers it's a UIView class, do you know what should I do now?

Comment: Is your Day View class is UIView?It should be UIViewController.You have added your plus button in DayView xib right?